# Suppress property definition warning with LLVM 3.0 on ObjC code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

Since Xcode 4.2 comes with LLVM 3.0 we're finally able to use *automatic synthesizeation*. You can turn it on by adding the following two flags to your `Other C Flags` in the `Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 - Language` section:

- `-Xclang`
- `-fobjc-default-synthesize-properties`

Now you can get rid of your `@synthesize` boiler plate code if you just want the default settings for your property synthesizeation (I guess we already use automatic reference counting).

When I hit build, the compiler warns me about missing `@synthesize` etc. statements, like so:

```
MyController.h:34:43: warning: property 'myProperty' requires method 'myProperty' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation [3]
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyClass *myProperty;
```

I prefer a warning-free build, so the **question** is: How can I **suppress** this kind of warnings because obviously they don't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure -Xclang is passed to the compiler

```
clang -x objective-c -Xclang -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -c TestClass.m -o TestClass.o
```

does not show any warnings while

```
clang -x objective-c -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -c TestClass.m -o TestClass.o
```

does which is by the way correct since no properties are synthesized

Here is the TestClass.m I used:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject * test;

@end

@implementation TestClass

@end
```

Comment: You got me in the right direction. When I'm doing a build from the CLI with `xcodebuild` there was no `-Xclang -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties`. I added these flags to project, when I'm moving them to target they show up in the build log. I can't say why this is, but now it works at least.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to suppress that warning using these C flags:

```
-Xclang -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -Wno-objc-property-implementation
```

Unfortunately, getters/setters don't get synthesized (...and in fact my app crashes...)